# How to solve trigonometric inequality $\cos\left(\frac{2\pi t}{12}\right) \ge \frac12$ without using calculators

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

I have a trig question. How do you I solve this, my professor put this kind of inequality in the exam where we can't watch table or use calculator so I suppose there is a fast way to do it.
$$\cos\left(\frac{2\pi t}{12}\right) \ge \frac12$$
Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple sketch with the trigonometric circle will show this inequality is equivalent to
\begin{align}
\cos\Bigl(\frac{\pi t}6\Bigr)\ge \cos\frac\pi 3&\iff -\frac\pi3\le\frac{\pi t}6\le \frac\pi3 \pmod{2\pi\mathbf Z} \\
&\iff-2\le t\le 2\pmod{12\mathbf Z}.
\end{align}

Comment: H , thk but how do you get to -pi/3<pit/6<pi/3 ?

Comment: Looking at the trigonometric circle. Didn't you learn in middle school that $\cos\frac\pi 3=\frac12$?

Comment: yeah of course but i don't understa how do you get te verse of the inequalities why is  -2<t<2 and not t>2 and t <-2?

Comment: You seem  to be forgetting that $\cos x$ decreases on $[0,\pi]ˆ$ (and I used that $\cos$ is an even function). On the trigonometric circle, this implies the point that represents $\frac{\pi t}6$ has a horizontal projection between $\frac 12$ and $1$.  Isn't it clear?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an outline: First solve $\cos\left(\frac{2\pi t}{12}\right) = \frac{1}{2}$ which comes down to $\cos\left(\frac{2\pi t}{12}\right) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$.

This gives two branches to solve: $\frac{2\pi t}{12}=\frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi$ and $\frac{2\pi t}{12}=-\frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi$.

You should be able to find $t=12k+2$ and $t=12k-2$. Since for $t=0$ the cosine is above $\frac{1}{2}$, should now be able to put all the pieces together, which is what I want you to try now.

Comment: Hi thk for your answer but  how i can understand if it's  -2<t<2 or t<-2 and t>2 ?